# How to get user's choice (ok, cancel) from android.content.Intent to uninstall an app

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a fragment that uses an intent to uninstall an app when they click uninstall.

```
View.OnClickListener removeButtonClick = new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View paramView) {
        PackageManager pm = ContextProvider.getContext().getPackageManager();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE, Uri.fromParts("package",
                    app.packageName, null));
        int result = 0;
        startActivityForResult(intent, result);
    }
};
```

When the activity finishes it successfully calls:

```
@Override 
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { 
    new MainActivity.UpdateDatabase().execute(); // update database
    ContextProvider.getContext().getFragmentManager().popBackStack(); // go back
}
```

But requestCode & resultCode are 0 and data is null regardless of whether the user pressed uninstall or cancel. How can I find out what they chose?

This is what I ended up doing:

```
@Override 
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { 
        Boolean found = false;
        PackageManager pm = ContextProvider.getContext().getPackageManager();
        List<PackageInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledPackages(0);
        for (PackageInfo pi : packages) {
            if (pi.packageName.equals(app.packageName)) {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found) { // User uninstalled app so update database and go back
            new MainActivity.UpdateDatabase().execute();                                    
            goBack();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know how to do that, but could you just use the package manager to see it package is still there or not?

Comment: Thanks @weston that is exactly what I did end up doing.